# Will the ribbon work in Mac without menu bar?

Tags: java, macos, ribbon

I'm developing a java application and I'm using ribbons instead of Menu bar, but as Mac depend completely on menu bar, should I modify my application to have a menu bar or this is not required?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number of applications that have been ported to Mac ignore the built-in menu bar and use their own internal menus, ribbons, buttons, icons, widgets, or other control elements.

For many experienced Mac users who are familiar with cross-platform applications and how they often differ in appearance, this may not be a deal breaker.

But for a less experienced user, you have broken a fundamental principle of all Mac OS X interface design. You have removed the menu from where users expect it to be and forced users to learn how your replacement works. This may not completely and permanently derail the user's understanding of your application, but why make anyone work harder to use your creation?

I will say that not **everything** belongs in an OS X menu bar. Plenty of application functionality is accessible only through the application proper. But common features like "Save" and "Copy" and "Print" — standard features that have standard keyboard shortcuts and standard menu arrangements — should be offered.